# reset cypress config on rerunning tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

i want to reset config like when we refresh the browser every time cypress test runs. i am using

```js
"content-type": "application/x-protobuf"
```

as default header but when one of my responses is json cypress change it to application/json by default.

this is my interceptor:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('intercept', (originalFn, { method, url }, options) => {
  method = 'POST'
  url = `${Cypress.env('EXTERNAL_API')}/${url}`
  options = {
    ...options,
    headers: Cypress.env('DEFAULT_HEADER'),
  }

  return originalFn(method, url, options)
})
```

Comment: How are you determining if the request should have `application/json` or `application/x-protobuf`? Is it certain endpoints are json and others are protobuf? Or is after say the first request, you'll always want json?

Comment: the successful responses are in protobuf formats and all network errors comes in json format.that's the dilemma.:)

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem. when i pass `body` instead of `fixture` in the interceptor , cypress forces the header to `application/json`. no way to change it.
to solve the problem i passed my `json` file as a `fixture` and set my custom header according to that.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('intercept', (originalFn, { method, url }, options) => {
  method = 'POST'
  url = `${Cypress.env('EXTERNAL_API')}/${url}`
  const isJsonHeader = options?.fixture?.toLowerCase()?.includes('.json') ? true : false
  options = {
    ...options,
    headers: isJsonHeader ? Cypress.env('JSON_HEADER') : Cypress.env('DEFAULT_HEADER'),
  }
  return originalFn(method, url, options)
})
```